# Change Chrome settings from an extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to override Chrome browser settings from an extension somehow?

I'm particularly interested in the global "Encoding" setting, which is set wrong by default and causes problems with the "filesystem:" URL scheme.

[image: Settings]

Comment: Did you ever end up finding something that you could use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not, as it may pose a security risk; the browser should not allow extensions modify its settings.